# Reading File and Mailing with PHP

Tags: php, email

I would like to read a data file (such as csv or txt) and mail it using PHP. I would like to be able to have at 5 minute pause in between each send of data.  I would also like to use the email field as the senders email. Any help would be appreciated.

Each data chunk will contain:

1. name
2. email
3. address
4. city
5. state
6. zip code
7. phone
8. comments

Comment: Show us your code. We are not working for free for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to write a newsletter application, so proceeding under that assumption:

You are probably not going to find this answer very helpful, but you should really consider using a newsletter service instead of writing your own code. The reason for this is that sending newsletters requires a LOT more effort and different skills than writing a simple script.

For example, but not exclusively:

- Setting up a mailserver correctly.
- Taking care about the reverse DNS.
- Managing digital signatures (DKIM) for your mail.
- Subscribing and tracking sender feedback loops.
- Tracking and avoiding DNSBL blocking lists for your server.
- etc.

If you really want to write your own code, you have been warned. Take a look at [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/str_getcsv) and [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) and don't be surprised if you get headaches from this project.